# Neumann series with random matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-matrices

Suppose that we have a sequence of random square matrices $\{A_n\}_{n\ge1}$ that converge to $0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$, i.e. $\|A_n\|\to0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm (or it might be any other norm since all norms are equivalent in the finite dimensional setting). I would like to use the following identity in my computations
$$
(I-A_n)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_n^k.
$$
However, the series on the right hand side has to converge (this is a [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)) because otherwise the identity does not make sense. Intuitively, since $A_n\to0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$, it seems that for large values of $n$ the identity should hold with a high probability. However, I am not sure if it is possible to make this argument rigorous.

> Is it possible to rigorously justify the use of the identity in this setting? For example, can we say that the identity holds for large values of $n$ since $\|A_n\|<1$ almost surely for large values of $n$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It's **not** true that $\|A_n\| < 1$ almost surely.

But
if $\|A_n\| \to 0$ in probability, for any $\delta > 0$ there is some $N$ such that $\mathbb P(\|A_n\| < 1) > 1 - \delta$ for all $n > N$.
Thus if $n > N$, the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_n^k$ converges with probability $> 1-\delta$.

However, though the probability of convergence for any particular $n > N$ is large, it could be that almost surely there are infinitely many $n$ for which the series does not converge.  For example, this would be the case if $A_n$ were independent with $\mathbb P(\sum_k A_n^k\ \text{diverges}) = 1/n$.
See [second Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result)